# Cancel angular bootstrap modal dimiss on backdrop click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want the modal to be dismissable if backdrop is clicked, but if the form in side is dirty I want to be able to cancel the dismiss, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by setting `backdrop: 'static'`.

> `backdrop` - controls presence of a *backdrop*. Allowed values: `true`
>   (default), `false` (no backdrop), `static` - backdrop is present but
>   modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window.

Afterwards add a click handler to the div:

```
$('div.modal.fade').on('click', function() {
    // close or dismiss the modal
});
```